# Getting around an HTML in-page pop-up ad?

Tags: browser, popups, advertisements

Trying to [watch a video on a website](http://tvrulez.com/video/niptuck-season-7-episode-2/), but there is a large CPA (Cost per action/PPA) popover that is sitting on the page blocking the view of the video in question.

The video plays, but how do I get around this popup blocking it?

Comment: F12 -> Search -> Click Element -> Delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(With firefox:)

Install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748), add it this script: [CPAlead remover](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/66224) & add http://tvrulez.com/* to the authorized pages of the script

(I have try with Adblock Plus & NoScript without result... The better result I got is to add @@|http://www.cpalead.com/mygateway.php?pub=* to adblock filters, but the overlay remains...)

Comment: Cool, this actually sounds like something that will work.  Will test when I get home

Answer (score 1):

Christ that's an annoying website.

If you disable adblock<sup>1</sup>, then enable it once you're on the page, you can block the image<sup>2</sup> and see through it - but the semitransparent overlay remains. It seems likely you could block it from ever appearing with NoScript, but I don't have that installed here. (Both of these options require firefox)

<sup>1</sup> to get in! That's not the way to get me to want to STOP blocking you!
<sup>2</sup> hosted at imageshack? They can stream video but not serve a static image?

Answer (score 1):

Another simple trick is that if you can figure out the hostname of the service that serves this annoying content, and it is different from the actual content provider that serves what you want, you can redirect the annoying server hostname to 127.0.0.1. Then, any content that could load annoying scripts or video ads will simply never load.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a developer you could edit it out of the page by using something like Firebug (it's an extension) from within Firefox. However I wouldn't recommend it unless you were familiar with HTML and website design.

Comment: I am a developer, and you can't do that.

Comment: I am a developer as well, and yes, you can edit HTML from Firebug, however it would only affect the local copy of the page within the browser. Not sure it would necessarily help you with every situation like that.